# on document load and if select option changed replace "select text"

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange, onload

I have a client that wants to have multiple distribution points, 1 located on the east coast  and 1 located on the west coast

The ecommerce solution I use does not support this. I figured out a work around by having multiple shipping options using the ship from postcode as a key.

I used some jQuery to change the "shipping option" to reflect the distribution location.

The idea works but my weakness is the jquery, if the user changes the shipping option a second time the options default back to the original ecommerce default options .

the code so far is

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    var sel = document.getElementById('ShippingOptions');

    for(var i = sel.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(sel.options[i].value == "-1")
            sel.options[i].text = "Select postage";
        if(sel.options[i].value == "75554")
            sel.options[i].text = "East Coast Distribution";
        if(sel.options[i].value == "75555")
            sel.options[i].text = "West Coast Distribution";

        $('#shippingSpan').text("Select postage");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do not mix jQuery and DOM.

It is not a great idea to change the select on the fly.
Instead have two selects or a hidden field that can be updated with the correct shipping.

What is the trigger for the change of distribution points?

And why is it an issue? If the user chooses the option with value 75554, is the text not East Coast and if he chooses 75555 is the text of the option not West Coast?

I am guessing (from the question and code provided) this is what you might want:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kRhH6/)

```
 var shippingOpts = { "75554":"East Coast Distribution", "75555":"West Coast Distribution" }

$(function() {    
  $('#ShippingOptions').on("change",function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#shippingSpan' ).text(
      (shippingOpts[val]) ? 
       shippingOpts[val] : 
       $("#ShippingOptions option:selected").text()
    );
  });

  // when page loads:
  $('#ShippingOptions').trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help... it worked fine at a page level but failed when implemented into the shopping cart

Comment: Then I need more information. Can you post a URL or some code at jsfiddle.net or send me the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery like this.

```
    $('#selectorid option:selected').each(function(i, item){
      // $(this).value() to access value 
      // $(this).text() to access text
      // $(this).value(" set value here "); same way for text

      // use if else ladder or switch case 

     });
```